# Understanding ABNF syntax "0<pchar>"

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4, grammar, abnf

In [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986.html#appendix-A), they defined the rule:

```
path-empty = 0<pchar>
```

For simplicity, let's assume `pchar` is defined:

```
pchar = 'a' / 'b' / 'c'
```

What does `path-empty` match and how is it matched?

I've read the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) page on ABNF. My guess is that matches the empty string (regex `^(?![\s\S])`). If that is the case, why even reference `pchar`? Is there not a simpler way to match the empty string in ABNF syntax without referencing another rule?

How could this be translated to ANTLR4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. `path-empty` derives the empty string.

In ABNF, the right-hand side of a rule must contain an `element`, which will be anything other than spaces, newlines, and comments. See [rfc5234](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5234), page 10. Given this syntax, there are several ways to define the empty string. `path-empty = 0<pchar>` is one way. It means "exactly zero of `<pchar>`". But, `path-empty = ""` and `path-empty = 0pchar` would also work. ABNF does not define whether one is preferred over the other.

Note, the rfc3986 spec uses a `prose-val`, i.e., `<pchar>` instead of the "rulename" `pchar` (or even `""`, `0pchar`, or just `<empty string>`). It's unclear why, but it has the same effect--`path-empty` derives the empty string. But, `<pchar>` is not the same as `pchar`. A prose value is a "last resort" way to add a non-formal description of the rule.

In Antlr4, the rule would just be `path_empty : ;`. Note, Antlr has a different naming convention that defines a strict boundary between lexer and parser. ABNF does not have this distinction. In fact, this grammar could be converted to a single Antlr lexer grammar, an exercise in understanding the power of Antlr lexers.